# Configuring a Google Apps domain + email with raspberry pi

Tags: web-server

Now that I have being playing with my raspberry pi for a week, I'm thinking about migrating my self hosted wordpress instance on Vlexofree.com to Ghost hosted on my pi.

I have two questions -

1. My primary email works off Google Apps. Is it possible to configure Google Apps on raspberry pi?
2. How can I host my domain from my pi?
   I think this will make it easy for me to create subdomains for all my little projects.

I think the second question would be quite common, I'll look for answers online but if someone could help with the first one that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

before everything else, I'd like to say that hosting anything worth hosting on raspberry pi is a silly idea, unless you don't care about your web-site at all and do not mind it going down at any random moment.

otherwise, it's very easy. 1) install LAMP stack with `apt-get` (you already have Linux, so there's only Apache, MySQL and PHP/Python/Perl left to install), 2) configure your raspberry to have IP address visible from the outside (probably somewhere in your router settings) 3) change your domain DNS configuration to point to your raspberry IP address, 4) have fun!

Comment: I'm planning to host my blog, It's not the most popular on the internet. I get a few hits here and there, it's more for the learning and fun that I want to try this.

But I do care about my google apps account very much, it's my primary email. Would you happen to know how to configure that to work?

I can access my pi over the internet with dyndns, can I use that for my domain as well?

Comment: Following your advice I think it's best that I setup a CNMAE record to point to my pi. That will leave everything else unchanged. This helped http://superuser.com/questions/127807/how-can-i-route-a-domain-to-my-box-at-home